# Evaluating $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {n - {n^2}\ln \left( {1 + {1 \over n}} \right)} \right)$

Tags: limits

How to compute this limit

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {n - {n^2}\ln \left( {1 + {1 \over n}} \right)} \right)$$

I took it from an exem. According to the solution, it's not $0$. I have no idea how to proceed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I don't know how to add an image to here, can u help me?

Comment: You can write it as $\frac {n^3-n^4 \ln (1+1/n)}{n^2}$ and useL'Hospital. The reason for the $n^2$ is hard to motivate without Taylor's theorem, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use *Taylor's formula* at order $2$ for $\;\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)$. You should find $\dfrac12$.

**Another hint,** without *Taylor's formula*:

Use *L'Hospital's rule* to find the limit of $\;\dfrac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$ when $x$ tends to $0$, then set $\;x=\dfrac1n$.

Comment: In more detail: [when $x\to 0$, $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)

Comment: we didn't learn about taylor yet, can't find something more simple?

Comment: Then, state in your question what you have done, what you have learned, what you can and cannot use. That **is** relevant.

Comment: ok, I found thats we do learn it, thank u.

Comment: @Yarben Sharabi: Please see my updated answer.